# onLocationchanged method not called in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

*I am using GoogleApiClient to get current Location in my fragment.When I was test in API 22 Emulator It give Current Location perfect *

**But**

*When I was tested In 23 Emulator Device It give 0 Location. when I was  debug code I find onLocationChanged Method of com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener  Not called Why ?*

Below is my code :

```
public class ContactUsFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("TAG", "OnCreate Called");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      buildGoogleApiClient();
}
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i("TAG", "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    createLocationRequest();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    Log.i("TAG", "CreateLocationRequest");
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10000;
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    //**************************
builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    //**************************

}
```

*OnClick Listener Of imageview *

```
  // ******************************** On Map Image Click Listener *************************************
    ivMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TAG", "On ImageView Click");            

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity())) {
                    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                        navigateToGoogleMap();
                    } else {
                        showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                } else {
                    requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,getActivity());
                }
            } else {


                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                    navigateToGoogleMap();
                } else {
                    showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }


        }

  @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    Log.i("TAG", "On Start");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.i("TAG", "On DestroyView");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    // currentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
    Log.i("TAG", "On Pause");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i("TAG","GoogleApiClient is Connected");
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}

public static void requestPermission(final String strPermission, final int perCode,final Activity _a) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(_a, strPermission)) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_contactus_linearlayout), "For Navigate we need Location Permission", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Allow", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_a, new String[]{strPermission}, perCode);
                    }
                });

        snackbar.show();

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_a, new String[]{strPermission}, perCode);
    }


}

public static boolean checkPermission(String strPermission, Context _c, Activity _a) {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(_c, strPermission);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


// ******************************** Get Permisson Request Result *************************************
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was " + grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
            Log.i("TAG", "Location Permission Granted");
            startLocationUpdates();
            navigateToGoogleMap();

            // \n is for new line
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + currentlatitude + "\nLong: " + currentlongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {
        Log.i("TAG", "For Navigation Location Permisson is Required");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location Permission Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location mCurrentLocation;

    Log.i("TAG", "OnConnected");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            // Note that this can be NULL if last location isn't already known.
            if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                // Print current location if not null
                Log.d("DEBUG", "current location: " + mCurrentLocation.toString());
                currentlatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
                currentlongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            }
            // Begin polling for new location updates.
            startLocationUpdates();

        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,getActivity());
        }
    } else {
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        // Note that this can be NULL if last location isn't already known.
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            // Print current location if not null
            Log.d("DEBUG", "current location: " + mCurrentLocation.toString());
            currentlatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            currentlongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        // Begin polling for new location updates.
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    Log.i("TAG", "StartLocationUpdates");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);

        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,getActivity());
        }
    } else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    Log.i("TAG", "StopLocationUpdates");
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("TAG", "onConnectionSuspended");
    if (i == CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (i == CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Network lost. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("TAG", "OnLocationChanged");
    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    currentlatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentlongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), connectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("TAG", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: For Marshmallow you need to write code for allowing permission, I've faced same problem

Comment: @Nisarg I all ready give permissions

Comment: Okay and In Emulator did you set your location manually?

Comment: @Nisarg i was tested on Genymotion device so it have feature to set  GPS Location

Comment: got your problem but sometimes you need to manually set location from that map option in GPS dialog

Comment: @Nisarg Emulator give current location when i was tested in its native map app

Comment: put permission code in onCreate of your fragment it should execute first

Comment: @Nisarg having same problem i was tried that also.